# Why I am not able to switch oracle home 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW3Hl.png)

I had changed the environment variable,
 echo %oracle_home% showing as 11g directory

but 
C:\Windows\system32>%path%

'G:\app\siva\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin' is not recognized as an internal or ex
ternal command,
operable program or batch file.

help me with this.

All the services are running.

Comment: did you look the system variables path?

Comment: Oracle home is one thing, the path (which should include `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin`) a different one. You must set both to appropriate values.

Comment: yes and I changed it to 11g path but still same

Comment: I opened a new session it is working now. I think I have to open the new session when changing environment variables

Answer (score 0):

you can change system variable path as you wish then restart

[image]

Comment: But If I have 2 DBs, 11g and 12c If I want to use both simultaneously, do I need to change the variable path every time?

Comment: define both of them